# PHP email, how to include variable in message

Tags: php

I have an upload script that I have purchased. I need to add some more functionality to it however and my php knowledge is pretty basic. What I need is for an email containing the file location to be sent out via email to a set address. Basically a notification that something has been uploaded.

I have worked out what part of the code these needs to go in, and have got as far as adding this which works perfectly:

```
// Send Email Notification
       $to = "info@email.co.uk";
       $subject = "A Website User uploaded files";
       $message = "The download link goes here. ";
       $from = "registrations@email.co.uk";
       $headers = "From:" . $from;
       mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

The next line of code in the script outputs the value I want to send in the message of the email like this:

```
$TMPL['message'] .= '<div class="success">Download: 
<a href="index.php?a=download&q='.$execLastRow[0].'" 
target="_blank">'.$_FILES['fileselect']['name'][$key].'</a></div>';
```

Obviously this is the wrong syntax but this is the gist of what Im trying to do:

```
// Send Email Notification
       $to = "info@email.co.uk";
       $subject = "A Website User uploaded files";
       $message = "Download: <a href="index.php?a=download&q='.$execLastRow[0].'" target="_blank">'.$_FILES['fileselect']['name'][$key].'</a>. ";
       $from = "registrations@email.co.uk";
       $headers = "From:" . $from;
       mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Assistance as always is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Edit

Appending to an existing string add `.` like `.=`

```
$message .= 'Download: <a href="index.php?a=download&q='.$execLastRow[0].'" target="_blank">'.$_FILES['fileselect']['name'][$key].'</a>';
```

@DevZer0 noticed that you need to add `$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";` to set the content type to HTML.

### Before edit

Because you start the string with `"` and then `href="`

So the first `"` in href is closing your string.

```
$message = 'Download: <a href="index.php?a=download&q='.$execLastRow[0].'" target="_blank">'.$_FILES['fileselect']['name'][$key].'</a>';
```

You could compare the row above with yours and check the color syntax.

Comment: That outputs: Download: <a href="index.php?a=download&q=19" target="_blank">dutty-mcmash.jpg</a>. as a single line of text in the email, how would I write it so it keeps the HTML too please?

Comment: Sadly thats still outputting the same thing in the body of the email

Comment: @WebblyBrown you need to set content-type to text/html. in the email header

Comment: Ahh ok so I need to add a MIME type for HTML to the header, thats working guys thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is to put variables in a string right?

```
  $message = 'Variable1: ' . $var1 . ', Variable2: ' . $var2 . ', Variable3: ' . $var3;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change -

```
$message = "Download: <a href="index.php?a=download&q='.$execLastRow[0].'" target="_blank">'.$_FILES['fileselect']['name'][$key].'</a>. ";
```

To

```
$message = 'Download: <a href="index.php?a=download&q='.$execLastRow[0].'" target="_blank">'.$_FILES['fileselect']['name'][$key].'</a>.';
```

Comment: That outputs: Download: <a href="index.php?a=download&q=19" target="_blank">dutty-mcmash.jpg</a>. as a single line of text in the email, how would I write it so it keeps the HTML too please?

Answer (score 0):

You could assign text like this.

```
$message = <<<HTML
"Download: <a href="index.php?a=download&q={$execLastRow[0]}" target="_blank">{$_FILES['fileselect']['name'][$key]}</a>. ";
HTML;
```